# Raspberry Pi model B scaling for 3.2" touchscreen

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have bought a 3.2" touchscreen for the Raspberry Pi model B that I have and it comes with a dvd containing a system image of Raspbian compatible with running the screen.

Now my problem is that the Pi is stretching the display way more over than the real resolution of the screen so I get half of the display or a portion of it and the rest is out of frame.

I have tried to change the resolution but there is no option except 320x240 and auto which sets it back to 320x240.

So is there anyway I can rescale the display or force the pi to render on some pixel values for length and width?